# iOS: Is there a way to stop users from rolling back to previous version of an App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, app-store

I recently made some updates regarding my SQLite database (regarding the new build) by removing a column's data. However, I noticed one issue. If the user updates to the new version of the App and then downgrades the app (assuming they don't uninstall the new version completely) the old version of the app won't work correctly.

The only thing I found was excluding older versions of an app from being installed on iTunes connect icloud section. However, I am not sure if this is enough. Any insight is appreciated.

Edit: Should I really worry about users installing an older version of an App? This seems like an extremely rare circumstance.

Comment: How does a user rollback the app to a previous version? I've had a SQLite database based app in the App Store since 2008 with scores of changes to the schema over those years and the thought of dealing with this situation has never entered my mind until reading this question. Interesting.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to downgrade the app. If it is possible, you could introduced a forced upgrade check with a backend service.

Comment: I don't think it is possible the normal way. I've found this. https://www.cultofmac.com/403848/how-to-restore-older-versions-of-ios-apps/. Plus I found older StackOverflow posts talking about disabling older builds on iTunes. Maybe I'm worried over nothing?

Comment: You have a resource on your web service that you check what version of the service it’s using. Or if it’s a serverless solution, you can use [Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren). Clearly, this won’t help you for old app installs, but it’s something you can do from this point forward.